# How do I actually see a list of my branches on GitHub?

Tags: github

Today I committed some code to GitHub. I'd like to be able to actually view it. How do I see a full list of branches where I've committed something?

Answer (score -1):

On Github your branches are in a dropdown list on the left side of the main display, just below the number of commits in the repo near the colored bar

Github by default only grabs your master branch... so a workflow where you branch off, do some work, checkout master and then push results in only one branch on github

To push a particular branch you can use:

```
git push origin <branch-name>
```

or according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885999/with-github-how-do-i-push-all-branches-when-adding-an-existing-repo) you can also push all branches with:

```
git push --all
```